# Localization for ENG/AR language is inconsistent

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, localization, arabic

I have been working on a bilingual site which shows Arabic and English content. I have stored value arabic and english values in `App_GlobalResources >> Resource file` with following names

1. Messages.ar-LB.resx
2. Messages.resx

**Syantax for fetching data from global resource**

Syntax for Jquery-->

```
"<%= Resources.Messages.userName %>"
```

or

```
<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("Messages", "userName ") %>
```

Aspx Codebehind -->

```
Resources.Messages.userName
```

Every page I use is inherits basepage in which i have overridden `InitializeCulture()` in which i set current culture to **EN-US or AR-LB** depending on user preference.

**Problem :-**  some of the pages render Arabic lables properly using jquery as well codebehind but fails to do in other pages. I am not able to find any significance difference between these pages.

Am i missing something here?

**UPDATE**:
This is how i set culture.

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
         SetCulture("ar-LB","ar-LB"); // Example
    }
protected void SetCulture(string name, string locale)
    {
          // parameters passed here-> (, ar-LB)
          Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(name);
          Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(locale);
    }
```

Comment: how do you set the culture?

Comment: Try disabling cache or configure the cache to vary on the language.

Comment: @jgauffin  Does caching affect Codebehind call as my codebehind calls are also returning wrong output.

Comment: @jgauffin: I was able to Solve JQUERY issue by changing extension of from `ar-LB` to `ar_SA`. I have made changes in Setculture function too.  However codebehind is still messed up.